# How to add element to a vector at the beginning?

Tags: c++, vector, int

I used push_back(elements) and reversed the vector later. Is there any way to do it in a straight forward way?

```
void main() {
  vector<int> arr;
  int input,size = 0 ;

   for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
     cin >> input;
     arr.push_back(input);
   }

   reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());
 }
```

Comment: You have this method in vector: `iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);`, so you can just use `arr.insert(arr.begin(), input);`

Comment: If you construct the vector by adding all elements from the start, then `std::vector` may not be the right container if you'e adding many elements.

Comment: Also your program is wrong because you use `size` uninitialized.

Comment: I will correct it Jabberwocky, I haven't compiled at the time of posting this question.

Comment: arr.insert(arr.begin(), value);